# Why is the # of tag followers increased when I subscribe AND follow a tag

Tags: bug

At for example the tag [amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsterdam) I can hover over the tag name itself in the right corner and a small pop-up will appear showing the amount of followers and a short description of the tag:

[image]

If I click the star, I favorite the tag, and the number of followers increases by one. This works as it should be:

[image]

However, if I click subscribe after that as well, the number of followers increases again, making me a duplicate follower:

[image]

Is this by design or is this a bug?

Comment: Somebody did `SELECT COUNT(*)...` instead of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)).....`

Comment: Stack exchange wide... I just tried it on avp.stackexchange.com and the same things happens.